# How to tell what fired IOS notification in Jailbroken phone

Tags: ios, notifications, push-notification, jailbreak, cydia

Is there a way to figure out what fired the IOS notification?

I want to be able to access a log of notifications and what fired them. I can access root files (b/c of jailbreak).

Answer (score 0):

THIS ANSWER IS PURELY BASED ON THEORY.
Try swizzle the post method and [NSThread callStackSymbols];
But I would say some search with hopper disassembler is the best idea